# Im trying to pull data from a file and build a dictionary inside the class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

First I dont know if this is possible or he correct way to go about it since im still in intro to programming but im trying to build a dictionary within a class from data pulled from a .txt file.  But the way to the professor wants us to pull the data from the file is by using the byte count method.  This is the first part of the question he asked.  Im not going to post the whole thing since im sure I can figure the rest out after this one hump.
Input Data
For each student, the following data will be read from a file: 
Each line (record) will have
•   student id ( 5 bytes)
•   student name (30 bytes) 
•   test 1 (3 bytes)
•   test 2 (3 bytes)
•   test 3 (3 bytes)

I've tried building it in a **init** and just doing it under a normal function.  The thing is if I do get it to build in the class I cant get it to work correctly to pull to the main function

```
class Grades:

    count = 0
    avg = 0
    studentDict = {}


    def __init__(self, userId, name, test1, test2, test3):
        self.userId = userId
        self.name = name
        self.test1 = test1
        self.test2 = test2
        self.test3 = test3

        openFile = open('Students.txt', 'r')



        for lines in openFile:
            userId = lines[:5].strip(' ')

            name = lines[5:35].strip(' ')

            test1 = lines[35:38].strip(' ')

            test2 = lines[38:41].strip(' ')

            test3 = lines[41:].strip(' ')

        openFile.close


    def setUserId(self, userId):
        self.userId = userId

    def getUserId(self):
        return self.userId

    def setName(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def setTest1(self, test1):
        self.test1 = test1

    def getTest1(self):
        return self.test1

    def setTest2(self, test2):
        self.test2 = test2

    def getTest2(self):
        return self.test2

    def setTest3(self, test3):
        self.test3 = test3

    def getTest3(self):
        return self.test3

myGrades = Grades()

print(myGrades.getUserId())
```

This is all I have because im trying to get it to print some of the results before I move on but this right here is giving me this error code,
TypeError: **init**() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'userId', 'name', 'test1', 'test2', and 'test3'

I would like it to print out in a dictionary

Comment: you are trying to instantiate class before reading a source file containing the initial attributes - the error is obvious. You don't have the needed parameters at instantiating phase

Answer (score 0):

When calling `myGrades = Grades()`, you are missing 5 arguments in your class constructor, as you declared it the following : `def __init__(self, userId, name, test1, test2, test3):`.
I think you should declare it with no arguments, and affect the class variable after reading the file. It should give something like that :

```
def __init__(self):

    openFile = open('Students.txt', 'r')

    for lines in openFile:
        userId = lines[:5].strip(' ')

        name = lines[5:35].strip(' ')

        test1 = lines[35:38].strip(' ')

        test2 = lines[38:41].strip(' ')

        test3 = lines[41:].strip(' ')

    openFile.close()

    self.userId = userId
    self.name = name
    self.test1 = test1
    self.test2 = test2
    self.test3 = test3
```

Also be careful, you are missing two parenthsis after the call of `close`.